# In Python 3, what is happening when I index a bytearray?

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, arrays

In Python 3, I can create a bytearray by encoding a string:

```
>>> foo = 'abc'
>>> bar = foo.encode('utf-8')
>>> bar
b'abc'
```

But when I index that byte array, I get something else:

```
>>> bar[0]
97
```

What is this and why isn't it

```
b'a'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a small int, because that's how indexing bytes is defined in [PEP 3137: "Immutable Bytes and Mutable Buffer"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3137/).

> ### Indexing
>
> Indexing bytes and bytearray returns small ints [...]
>
> Assignment to an item of a bytearray object accepts an int in range(256). [...]

If you want `b'a'` then slice instead.

```
3>> b'abc'[0:1]
b'a'
```

Comment: So technically you ARE getting 'a', just not in the form you want.

Answer (score 1):

Byte arrays are data, not characters, so individual elements are values 0-255.

Answer (score 1):

The value 97 is the UTF-8 encoding of the character `a`. Most common characters are encoded in UTF-8 in the same way they are encoded in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).